# Ubuntu alt-tab does not keep correct order but only when toggling first from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

This seems to be pretty consistent now. Repeated alt-tab (release both between each press) from chrome seems to pop chrome off the stack and then toggles between the 2nd and 3rd apps leaving chrome out of that cycle. The correct behaviour is observed for any other app that I've tested.

Any ideas about this weird behaviour or how to debug further?

UPDATE:

Linux ... 4.15.0-88-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 11 20:11:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME

UPDATE: restarting and updating (a few cycles) and the problem is currently not present. I suspect this is just some weird state specific to chrome. Still interested if anyone has hunches. Will post more if it re-appears.

Comment: Ubuntu version, desktop environment?

Comment: sorry forgot. Updated now.